# Как использовать Properties из JavaFX

Tags: javafx, properties

У меня есть метод, который возвращает изменяющийся со времени int. Я хочу создать Property из JavaFX, значение которого бы изменялось с изменением значения возвращающегося int, затем я бы хотел к нему добавить слушатель, который бы следил за изменением значения данного Property и, когда значение изменится, делал определённые действия. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
 IntegerProperty intProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1024);
    final ChangeListener changeListener = new ChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void changed(ObservableValue observableValue, Object oldValue,
          Object newValue) {
        System.out.println("oldValue:"+ oldValue + ", newValue = " + newValue);
      }
    };

    intProperty.addListener(changeListener);
    intProperty.set(5120);
```

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/ChangeListenerforIntegerProperty.htm

Comment: Такой вариант мне известен, мне нужно, чтобы через равные промежутки времени вызывался метод, который возвращает int, этот int устанавливается как значение Property, а потом срабатывает слушатель. Я это сделал через Timeline, но мб есть вариант без его это сделать, используя только Properties?

Comment: Звучит как цикл с таймаутом или планировщик, внутри которого меняется значение у property. Можно объект Task использовать или что-то более изящное.